# How to add a row to table at a specific position

Tags: text-processing

How to add a row to table after header in a tab-separated file?

My input file looks like this:

```
ID_1     ID_2   v1               C   V3      V4
1878372 2253734 SAMN06396112     20481   NA      DNA                
1884646 2275341 SAMN06432785     20483   NA      DNA     
1860945 2277481 SAMN06407597     20488   NA      DNA
```

I am looking for following desired output:

```
ID_1    ID_2     v1              C      V3      V4
   C       C       C               B      B       A
1878372 2253734 SAMN06396112     20481   NA      DNA                
1884646 2275341 SAMN06432785     20483   NA      DNA     
1860945 2277481 SAMN06407597     20488   NA      DNA
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
line='  C       C       C               B      B       A'
sed -e "1a\\
$line" < input.txt
```

That's a hard newline within the double-quoted string. In Bash/Ksh/Zsh, you could use

```
sed -e $'1a\\\n'"$line" < input.txt
```

If the line to add contains backslashes, you'll need to double them to escape them from special processing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach with `awk`, using a variable as the string to be inserted:

```bsh
$ foo="C\tC\tC\tB\tB\tA"
$ awk -v s="$foo" 'NR == 2 { print s} { print }' input.txt | column -t
ID_1     ID_2     v1            C      V3  V4
C        C        C             B      B   A
1878372  2253734  SAMN06396112  20481  NA  DNA
1884646  2275341  SAMN06432785  20483  NA  DNA
1860945  2277481  SAMN06407597  20488  NA  DNA
```

`column -t` is used to tidy up the columns.

Comment: I don't know if the `column` command is really necessary (or a good idea); since the OPs input is TSV, I would imagine that the output is also desired to be "simply" tab-separated ...

Answer (score 0):

assumming `input.txt` and `line.txt` are respectively input and line to add.

```
sed -e '1r line.txt' input.txt > output.txt
```

to edit directly `input.txt`

```
printf "%s\n" "1r line.txt" w q | ed input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"; str="C\tC\tC\tB\tB\tA"}NR==1{$0=$0 ORS str}1' input
```

- `FS=OFS="\t"` Input field separator and Output field separator are set to `\t`.
- `NR==1{$0=$0 ORS str}` A new record is added after record one. `$0` is current input record followed by newline (Because default value of `ORS` is `"\n"`) and then followed by `str` we created in `BEGIN` rule.
- `1` is `awk`'s idiom for printing.